# Shopify: Pass values from non-Shopify site to Shopify Checkout and get URL

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I have a static (non-Shopify) HTML and JS website with a shopping cart where its functionality is carried out using JS and Jquery. I need to pass my cart values to Shopify and take the user directly to the Shopify Checkout page when user clicks on the checkout button on my site. I need to pass cart values to Shopify and load the checkout page on the browser. How can I do this? I'm new to Shopify and I need some guidance on how to do this.

Comment: Use [Shopify Storefront API](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api) to create [Checkout](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/checkouts)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to variant ids and quantities in the cart, you can use a permalinks for this purpose. Example - http://yourstore.com/cart/70881412:1,70881382:1

More details here - https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Cart-Use-permalinks-to-pre-load-the-cart/td-p/613702

Comment: This seems like an easy method.