# Is it possible to checkout on any Shopify store with just API calls?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, shopify

I'm working on a bot for learning purposes and I have this endpoint that is able to retrieve the cart data.

```
router.get("/cart", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const cartResponse = await fetch(`https://${currentStore}/cart.js`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "cookie": cartCookies,
        }
    }).then(response => response.json());
    res.status(200).send({ cart: cartResponse });
});
```

The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to create the checkout process given the information from the cart. Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: Possible solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65062866/4287624

Comment: You could use selenium or a headless browser solution if you want to automate but don't need your solution to be exclusively API calls

Comment: @mostlyAsking7179 Yeah I was originally trying to go the headless route but I'm looking for speed.